# Is there any correction for varnasankara?

Tags: smriti, varnashrama

Is it true that the varna sankara in a lineage gets cleared after 7 generations, if it is not repeated in successive generations?
If yes, please provide some scriptural evidence to support it.

Comment: Varnasankara born are not mentally ill people. They are normal human beings capable of attaining enlightenment as equally or more profoundly as so called Brahmin born. Varnasankara means, *intermarriage of people belonging to different Varnas.* So, there is no need for the correction. You only have to follow Dharma which you believe to be righteous. (I am Brahmin born, if you think varna is by birth)

Comment: Hi, this was not asked to belittle or show disgrace to Varna sankaras. I just wanted to know if it's reversible as per shastras.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Is it true that the varna sankara in a lineage gets cleared after 7
> generations,

Yes, it is true. See:

> 18 From men of the four classes, a Brahmin woman gives birth
> respectively to Brahmins, Sutas, Magadhas, and Can dalas;
>
> 19 from the same men, a Ksatriya woman gives birth respectively to
> Murdha¯vasiktas, Ksatriyas, Dhıvaras, and Pulkasas;
>
> 20 from the same men, a Vais´ya woman gives birth respectively to Bhr
> ˚ jyakanthas, Mahisyas, Vais´yas, and Vaidehas;
>
> 21 and from the same men, a Sudra woman gives birth respectively
> to Paras´avas, Yavanas, Karanas, and Sudras. That is the
> opinion of some.
>
> 22 **By successively marrying persons of the higher or the lower class,
> in the seventh generation the offspring moves to the one or the other
> class;**
>
> 23 in the fifth, according to the Teachers.
>
> 24 This is true also in
> the case of those born to parents belonging to different mixed classes
>
> *Dharmasutras of Gautama 4.18-4.24*

Comment: Isn't only Pratilom marriage banned ? 
Anulom marriage creates 100 percent pure children. Children born from Anulom marriage have varna of the father as far as I know

Comment: @river yes only Pratiloma marriage is censured.