# How can fault created in varnashankar be corrected?

Tags: varna

Can someone explain [in detail how fault created in varnashankar child be corrected](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/48136/23709) ?
Suppose a brahmin man marries a shudra woman , the child will be Parsarva.
Now can this Parsava man marry a Brahmin woman ?

Also can the fault created by Pratilom marriage be corrected ?

I think fault created in varnashankar child due to anulom marriage can be corrected. The reason is I don't find the presence of castes born from anulom marriage(eg- Parsava, Ugra etc) in puranic and historic texts but the presence of [castes born from pratiom marriage (eg- Soota, Nishada, Chandala, Maagadha etc) was very prominent](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uZOtn.jpg),indicating fault created due to pratilom marriage can't be rectified , while the fault due to anulom marriage can be rectified.

Are there any examples like this ?
Vidura can be an example , [he married a Ugra woman.](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/52217/23709)