# Is there any mention of presence of Ambasta caste community in Puranic or historic text?

Tags: caste-system, marriage

A caste in India claim to be Ambasta . But there is a confusion , if it is the name derived from Ambasta as in Manusmriti (Brahman Father + Vaishya mother)  [or from Amba devi.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ambashtha)

I am asking this as I want to know if Anulom marriage [where the wife is two or more varna lower is okay or not](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/53673/how-can-fault-created-in-varnashankar-be-corrected)

I think Anulom marriage of any type is okay, that is whey there is no presence of caste communities born from [Anulom marrige while caste communities born from Pratilom marriage was very prominent.](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/53675/are-there-presence-of-caste-communities-born-from-anulom-marriage-in-historic-an) (This is just my opinion)

So,

Is there any mention of presence of Ambasta caste **community**  in Puranic or historic text ?

Historic - Mahabharata and Ramayan.